# Why does FileMaker Pro show data instead of field names in layout mode?

Tags: filemaker

Why does my FileMaker Pro database show the data in the fields when I enter layout mode? Shouldn't it show the field names?

Comment: You couldn't proof-read your question at all?

Comment: other than whats typo in the title whats wrong with my question ? I think you just like to down vote people

Comment: @mcgrailm I don't down-vote people, only poorly asked questions. I also removed my down-vote until you rolled your question back to it's grammatically broken state.

Comment: Why would you revert your question to a revision featuring bad grammar?

Comment: @meagar I don't need you to correct my English there's a reason why my programmer and not a writer you understood the question as it stood in for the record file FileMaker is one word not two

Comment: @mcgrailm If you're not comfortable with others editing your questions, [you are on the wrong site](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing).

Comment: @mcgrailm - I've just rolled back your revert as the grammar was atrocious, which **makes it harder for people to give you an answer**. If you actually want people to answer, accept the improvements to your question with good grace. =)

Comment: Remember, your questions aren't just for you. They're for everyone who googles the same issue and lands here. A little editing *now* can make everyone's life more pleasant later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you have Show Sample Data turned on in the View menu.